# try/catch around reference assignment

Tags: c++, reference, try-catch

I would like to catch an exception from a method that returns a reference, without catching the same exception from a later call which uses the reference. For example:

```cpp
try {
    Something &o = myMap.at(myIndex);
    foo(o);
} catch(std::out_of_range &e) {
    // If this was thrown by myMap.at, we can handle it
    // If this was thrown by foo, we can't, and need to propagate it
}
```

So I'm looking to do something like this:

```cpp
Something &o;
try {
    o = myMap.at(myIndex);
} catch(std::out_of_range &e) {
    // Handle the error
}
foo(o);
```

But of course, that's not valid. I can think of ways to wrap `foo`'s exceptions in another exception then unwrap it outside the `try`, but that's rather messy. Is there a better way?

MCVE can be found here: https://ideone.com/DJHxpO

Comment: I assume that `foo` can throw `std::out_of_range` too? Otherwise it wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude in my specific use-case, `foo` is not known in advance, so I have to assume it could throw *anything*.

Comment: However, if you remember that exceptions (when thrown) are expensive in C++, and shouldn't really be used for validation, it might be a good idea to perhaps have a separate check if the key `myIndex` exists in the map first.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I agree, though it sounds like this isn't the actual function throwing something. Hopefully the real exception isn't an exception that could've been easily prevented.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes the exception in this case is truly exceptional, not just run-of-the-mill validation errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an immediately invoked lambda expression:

```
Something &o = [&]() -> decltype(auto) {
    try {
        return myMap.at(myIndex);
    } catch(std::out_of_range &e) {
        // Handle the error
        // Return some other object for o to refer to.
    }
}();
foo(o);
```

Comment: Rather verbose, but seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Dave, Without the need for a reference, it would be a bit simpler: `[&] { ... }()`. I wouldn't call that verbose considering the rest is code you write anyway. The need for the explicit return type is a bit annoying, though, and there's a small chance it might one day look like `[&]() => { ... }()` instead, though I'd be more hopeful when the body is a simple expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pointer instead:

```
Something *o; // initialize it with nullptr if necessary
try {
    o = &myMap.at(myIndex);
} catch(std::out_of_range &e) {
    // Handle the error
}
foo(*o);      // check whether it's nullptr before dereference if necessary
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I prefer chris' solution, since it keeps C++'s non-nullable semantics. I guess a line `Something &useThisO = *o;` just after the try would at least put this in one place, but there's still the risk that the catch block could cope with the error and forget to set `o`, leading to a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good use case for `boost::optional` (std:: in c++17).

You don't really want to generate or handle and exception because the item not being in the map is not an exceptional circumstance.

I think I would express it like this:

```
int myIndex = 1;
foo(maybe_at(myMap, myIndex).value_or_eval([]()->Something& {
    // perform error code here
    return default_something;
}));
```

Full code example here:

```
#include <map>
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

template<class Container>
struct container_traits
{
    using maybe_const_type = std::remove_reference_t<Container>;
    using container_type = std::decay_t<Container>;
    using is_const = std::is_const<maybe_const_type>;
    using key_type = typename container_type::key_type;
    using raw_mapped_type = typename container_type::mapped_type;
    using mapped_type = std::conditional_t<is_const::value, std::add_const_t<raw_mapped_type>, raw_mapped_type>;
    using mapped_reference = std::add_lvalue_reference_t<mapped_type >;
};

template<class Container, class Key>
auto maybe_at(Container&& container, Key&& key)
{
    using traits = container_traits<Container>;
    using result_type = boost::optional<typename traits::mapped_reference>;

    auto result = result_type {};
    auto ifind = container.find(key);
    if (ifind != container.end()) {
        result = ifind->second;
    }
    return result;
}


struct Something {};

void foo(Something&) {}
void foo(const Something&) {}

std::map<int, Something> myMap1;
const std::map<int, Something> myMap2;

auto default_something = Something{};

int main() {

    int myIndex = 1;

    foo(maybe_at(myMap1, myIndex).value_or_eval([]()->Something& {
        // perform error code here
        return default_something;
    }));

    foo(maybe_at(myMap2, myIndex).value_or_eval([]()->Something const& {
        // perform error code here
        return default_something;
    }));

}
```

Comment: tbh I was only using `map.at` as a simple example of a method which returns a non-const reference and can throw. I agree that an optional return type makes more sense for that particular case, but I only intended to demonstrate the abstract situation without needing to show more code.

Comment: @Dave sure. Still, optional is what this kind of use-case is designed for.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way, which works with all versions of C++, would be

```
bool mapped = false;
try {
    Something &o = myMap.at(myIndex);
    mapped = true;
    foo(o);
} catch(std::out_of_range &e) {
     if (mapped) throw;
     //   if we get to here, the exception was thrown by myMap.at()
}
```

This also avoids the need to make the reference refer to some other object if `myMap.at()` fails.

Comment: This is a nice way of handling it, with the advantage that it allows more types of error handling than chris' answer, and is safer than songyuanyao's answer. I'll keep it in mind if I find myself in a similar situation where I need more flexibility in the error handling (my current situation just needs to process the exception and throw a new one with more information).